# How to manage PK when a view must be called with it

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Hi guys I have an issue with my private keys. 
I do not know what is the problem if someone could give me a hand it would be greatly appreciated.

the errror that I get is : Generic detail view ProjectDetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug

my models are the following:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = '')
    team_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey(MyUser, blank=True, null=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(MyUser, related_name="members")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.team_name


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_id = models.ForeignKey(Team, blank=True, null=True)
    project_hr_admin = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser', blank=True, null=True)
    candidat_answers = models.ManyToManyField('survey.response')

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs = {'pk1' : self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my views :

```
class HomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name= 'index.html'

class LinkTeam(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'link_project.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        #team2 = Team.objects.all().filter(team_hr_admin = self.request.user)
        queryset = Team.objects.filter(team_hr_admin=self.request.user)
        return queryset

def TeamSelect(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user, request.POST)
        if select_form.is_valid():
            data = select_form.cleaned_data['team_choice']
            obj2 = Project.objects.filter(project_hr_admin=request.user)
            obj3 = obj2.latest('id')
            if obj3.team_id == None:
                obj3.team_id = data
                obj3.save()
                obj4 = obj3.team_id
                obj5 = obj4.members.all()

                for i in obj5:
                    current_site = get_current_site(request)
                    message = render_to_string('acc_join_email.html', {
                        'user': i.first_name,
                        'domain':current_site.domain,
                        })
                    mail_subject = 'You have been invited to SoftScores.com please LogIn to get access to the app'
                    to_email = i.email
                    email = EmailMessage(mail_subject, message, to=[to_email])
                    email.send()
                messages.success(request, 'test')
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('website:ProjectDetails', kwargs={'pk1':obj3.id}))
            else:
                print('this project has already a team')
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')

    else:
        select_form = EditSelectTeam(request.user)
    return render(request,'link_project.html',
                            {'select_form':select_form })

class HRIndex(generic.ListView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "HR_index.html"
    model = Project

class CandidateIndex(TemplateView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "candidate_index.html"

class EmployeeIndex(TemplateView):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    template_name = "employee_index.html"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeIndex, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        surveys = Survey.objects.filter(is_published=True)
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            surveys = surveys.filter(need_logged_user=False)
        context['surveys'] = surveys
        return context

class ProjectCreate(CreateView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    model = Project
    fields = ['name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.project_hr_admin = self.request.user
        return super(ProjectCreate, self).form_valid(form)

class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        try:
            team_name = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
            context['team_name'] = team_name
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        return context

class EmployeeDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = MyUser
    template_name = 'Employee_Details.html'


    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return get_object_or_404(MyUser, pk=self.kwargs['pk2'], members__project=self.kwargs['pk1'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        employee_name = MyUser.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        team_list = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all()
        team_list_pop = Project.objects.get(id=self.kwargs['pk1']).team_id.members.all().exclude(id=self.kwargs['pk2'])
        context={
            'employee_name' : employee_name,
            'team_list' : team_list,
            'team_list_pop' : team_list_pop
        }
        return context

class TeamCreate(CreateView):

    model = Team
    fields = ['team_name']
    template_name = 'team_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        valid = super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)
        form.instance.team_hr_admin = self.request.user
        obj = form.save()
        #SELECT * FROM project WHERE user = 'current_user' AND team_id = NULL
        obj2 = Project.objects.get(project_hr_admin=self.request.user, team_id=None)
        obj2.team_id = obj
        obj2.save()
        return valid
        return super(TeamCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        project = Project.objects.get(team_id=None, project_hr_admin=self.request.user)
        return project.get_absolute_url()
```

my urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^hr_index/$', views.HRIndex.as_view(), name='hr_index'),
    url(r'^candidate_index/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(),name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^employee_index/$', views.EmployeeIndex.as_view(),name='employee_index'),
    url(r'^addproject/$', views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='add_project'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/addteam/$', views.TeamCreate.as_view(), name='add_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam/$', views.LinkTeam.as_view(), name='link_team'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/linkteam2/$', views.TeamSelect, name='team_select'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data2/$',views.TeamChartData.as_view(), name='TeamChartData'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/$',views.EmployeeDetailView.as_view(), name='EmployeDetails'),
    url(r'^project/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)/(?P<pk2>[0-9]+)/api/chart/data/$',views.EmployeeChartData.as_view(), name='EmployeeChartData'),
```

What am I messing up here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DetailView`'s [`get_object`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_object) method is looking for `pk` url argument. Because you have only `pk1` url argument it raise error. You need to rename argument in url to `pk`:

```
url(r'^project/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.ProjectDetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails')
```

or override `get_object` method like you did in `EmployeeDetailView`.

You can also try to define [`pk_url_kwarg`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) inside `ProjectDetailView` like this:

```
class ProjectDetailView(generic.DetailView, LoginRequiredMixin):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    model = Project
    template_name = 'project_details.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'pk1'
```

In this case you need not to change url pattern or override `get_object`.

Comment: Now I get as well that def TeamSelect got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk1' any idea ?

Comment: @Ben2pop for function based view you need to define url's arguments as function arguments, like this: `def TeamSelect(request, pk1=None):`. Just add `pk1` argument to TeamSelect function.